# JUnit test related to criteriaBuilder

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to write a unit test for a method inside a dao object in which it is using an `EntityManager` to get a `CriteriaBuilder` and then use it to `createQuery`, how to do a mocking of the `CriteriaBuilder` so that it could go on to create the query?

```
@Component
public class MyDao {

 @PersistenceContext
 EntityManager entityManager;

 public List<MyEntity> mySearch(Integer offset, Integer Limit) {
   CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> query = builder.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
   //rest of implementation
   
   return this.entityManager.createQuery(query).setFirstResult(offset).getResultList():
}


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestDao {

 @InjectMocks
 private MyDao myDao;

 @Mock
 private EntityManager entityManager;

 @Test
 public void testSearch() {
   //how to mock entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder() that the created builder
   //could be used to createQuery 
   List<MyEntity> result = myDao.search(0, 10);
 } 
}
```

Comment: I always advise not to use mocks when testing JPA queries. JPA is a complex API, when testing with mocks you only prove that you called some methods on it - you dont check if you picked the right sequence of methods to get your result. You will be much better off if you test against a db (ideally, same db engine you use on prod - either embedded or dockerized)